# Argo workflow wait pod is not showing processes with command docker ps on GKE

Tags: docker, google-kubernetes-engine, argo-workflows, argo-events, argo

I am running Argo Workflow in GKE and workflow does not show container id while running following command

```
docker ps --all --no-trunc --format={{.Status}}|{{.Label \"io.kubernetes.container.name\"}}|{{.ID}}|{{.CreatedAt}}
```

Because of this wait container is stuck in a loop, searching for main container to be finished.

Comment: Please modify the body text of this post to include an explicit question. The text in the post currently reads as a comment.

Comment: Check what container runtime is used in your cluster. For newer GKE versions it's **containerd** instead of docker. See [GKE docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/using-containerd). If it's containerd, docker ps will not show any containers.

Comment: I just changed the workflow controller to k8s and it worked. Seems like wait container needs to be privileged in order to use docker file at /etc path

Answer (score 1):

Just change **containerRuntimeExecutor: docker** in workflow-controller-configmap.yaml because in the latest image of argoproj/workflow-controller
default value of containerRuntimeExecutor is changed from docker to emissary.

https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/workflow-controller-configmap.yaml
https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/workflow-controller-configmap/

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the workflow controller to k8s and it worked. Seems like wait container needs to be privileged in order to use docker file at /etc path

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).